# Checking the SHL x86 assembly instruction for overflow

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-overflow

What is an easy way to check after the `SHL EAX, CL` instruction whether the theoretical result (EAX times (2 power CL)) fits into EAX? The question is about unsigned integers.

I hoped for something like checking the carry flag in the case of `ADD` instructions or checking EDX in the case of `MUL` instructions.

Comment: Unfortunately the carry is only useful for single bit shifts. If the count is constant you can use `test` to check if any high order bits are set. Since you mention `mul` which produces double width result, you can also use `shld` to do something similar.

Comment: `neg cl` / `shr reg,cl` with a copy of the original shift input will keep only the bits that were shifted out by the original `shl`.  So ZF=1 from that means no overflow.  (But you need to `mov edx, eax` before the first shift, or use BMI2 `shlx` to copy-and-shift). Or like Jester said SHLD to shift bits into a zeroed register like `xor edx,edx` / `shld edx, eax, cl` / check ZF / `shl eax, cl`.  That's probably faster on Intel where `shld reg, reg, cl` is "only" 4 uops, vs. more on AMD especially before Zen 3.  This only checks for unsigned overflow, not shifting out any set bits.

Comment: If you wanted to check for the bits shifted out to all have the same value as the new MSB of EAX (signed overflow), that would be different.

Comment: "This only checks for unsigned overflow, not shifting out any set bits." @PeterCordes I found this line confusing. I assume now it means "this checks for unsigned overflow" and "this checks that we are not shifting out any set bits", but the "not" connective here got me mixed up reading this initially.

Comment: @ecm: you're right, clunky phrasing I should have avoided.  I meant it checks that we haven't shifted out any set bits, which is what we need for checking unsigned overflow.  (As opposed to signed, where shifting out set bits from the top of a small negative number isn't a problem, as long as all the bits we shift out are equal to each other.  Like maybe if `dst + 1` has exactly one set bit?  But that misses the case where `dst = 1` but that bit was a signed-overflow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this by checking *after* the instruction.  It does not record information about unsigned overflow, i.e. whether *any* 1 bits were shifted out.  The carry flag only contains the *last* bit that was shifted out.

For instance, if EAX = 0xF0000000 and CL = 7, then `SHL EAX, CL` will leave EAX = 0 and the carry flag clear.  You would get exactly the same architectural result, including all the other flag values, if the input was EAX = 0x00000000.  So even though one has an overflow and the other does not, there is no way to distinguish them after the fact.

You can test *before* the instruction whether it will overflow, by checking if the top CL bits of EAX are zero.  For instance (untested):

```
    MOV    EBX, 0x80000000
    SAR    EBX, CL    ; now top CL+1 bits of EBX are 1
    SHL    EBX, 1     ; now top CL bits of EBX are 1
    TEST   EBX, EAX   ; mask off all lower bits
    JNZ    will_overflow
```

Some other possible algorithms (maybe better) were suggested in the comments, such as `SHLD`.

Just because I happened to be thinking about it, here's a check for *signed* overflow, which occurs if and only if the top CL+1 bits are not all equal.

```
    MOV    EBX, 0x80000000
    SAR    EBX, CL      ; now top CL+1 bits of EBX are 1
    MOV    EDX, EAX     ; copy the input to be shifted
    AND    EDX, EBX     ; mask off all but top CL+1 bits
    JZ     no_overflow  ; top bits all 0
    CMP    EDX, EBX     
    JE     no_overflow  ; top bits all 1
    ; else handle overflow
```

For the one-bit shift instruction `SHL EAX, 1`, then the carry flag does exactly indicate whether unsigned overflow occurs.  Also, the overflow flag indicates whether *signed* overflow occurs.  In fact, all of CF, OF, ZF, SF, PF are set exactly the same as they would be for the mathematically equivalent `ADD EAX, EAX`.  So if you are optimizing for space over speed, then instead of `SHL EAX, CL`, you could consider a loop, iterating CL times and executing `SHL EAX, 1` followed by `JC overflow_occurred` on each iteration.

Comment: If you have multiple things to shift with the same shift count, you can reuse the mask with just `test`/`jnz overflow` per shift making this the obvious best choice for that case.  For a single shift, other strategies might be better or not since this avoids destroying the shift count in CL, and avoids `shld` which is slow on AMD.  (Also, `add ebx, ebx` is cheaper on some CPUs than `shl ebx, 1`, since `add` can run on ports that don't have a shift ALU, and we expect the surrounding code to have at least one more shift.)

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined in what sense a method should be "easy", but if you afford two registers for temporary values, the check is trivial - just shift back (reverse direction) by the same width with the same shift kind ("logical" vs. "arithmetic"), and compare with the original value. This would look like:

```
    ; esi, edi - arbitrary choice
    mov esi, eax ; save the original value to later comparison
    shl eax, cl ; <-- the shift to check
    mov edi, eax
    shr edi, cl  ; <-- the opposite action
    cmp esi, edi ; equal to the original value?
    jne overflow_happened
```

This method is universal for processors that have cheap shifts (99.9%, with barrel shifter), and among all four variants of single linear shifts (sal, shl, sar, shr - for x86). It automatically "adjusts" its logic for the shift type. Also, you don't need to calculate a mask, test against two different signs (for signed values), etc.

For ISAs where shifts donʼt set condition codes at all (even if they are present, like in AArch64), or condition codes donʼt reflect full-width number interpretation (like in x86), the described method is the only really easy. So universal compilers tend to use it over different architectures. A few architectures (example: SystemZ) reflect arithmetic result in condition codes, but legacy - and easiness of reverse check - resulted in absence of this beside rare cases.

Comment: ARM can set condition codes from shifts, but only if the shift is an instruction by itself, like `lsrs r0, r1, r2` (aka `mov r0, r1, lsr r2` in ARM mode), not like `adds r0, r1, lsr r2`.  (The S suffix on the mnemonic indicates that the instruction should set flags.  In Thumb2, the flag-setting encoding is normally smaller, if either encoding can be 16-bit).  Fun fact: unlike `adds`, `ands` sets Carry based on the shift:  [Why does the flags in ARM are not affected if there a change in the Register?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281535)

Comment: @PeterCordes In AArch64 they dropped setting condition codes by shifts at all. I was orienting on it. I'll clarify this.